# aspdotnetstorefront - How to change Product image tooltip that shows "Click here for larger image"?

Tags: image, tooltip, aspdotnetstorefront

When I mouse over a Product image the tooltip shows "Click here for larger image"

How can we change this to show the product name or image name for better Seo?

This is coming from within the Get Product Image call, Someone suggested I could simply string replace the output in the product XmlPackage and replace the  "Click here for larger image"  with your better for SEO version... but I need an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you login to the Admin section of your storefront, and go to "Configuration -> Localization -> String Resource Manager". Once in string resource manager search for "showproduct.aspx.19". Then just click edit and change it to whatever you want the tooltip to show.